# How to create a matrix by itself and have a letter equal to it?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

[image]

I am trying to exactly duplicate this picture here in LaTex. 
... so far all i have is

```
 \[ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c \end{array} \right)\]
```

which creates just the matrix on the left but i don't know how to insert the D = and the rest of the image.

Much help would be greatly appreciated 
Thank you much

Comment: put `D=` before the `\left\(`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle putting D= before the \left\ part just puts it at the left most side i want to have it by itself in the middle of the paper

Comment: Your image shows D= to the left of the matrix and the markup for that is `D=` If that doesn't produce what you want I can't guess what you want, for the rest you want `\Longrightarrow D^3 = \left another matrix...`

Answer (score 5):

Or maybe is something like this what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ D = \begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c \end{pmatrix} \Longrightarrow 
D^3 = \begin{pmatrix}
a^3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b^3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c^3 \end{pmatrix} \] 
\end{document}
```

Is the same code of Ignasi, but I used the `pmatrix` environment from the `amsmath` package. For me is easier to write a matrix in this way.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ D = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c \end{array} \right) \Rightarrow 
D^3 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a^3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b^3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c^3 \end{array} \right) \] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: or perhaps  `\Longrightarrow`